# How to test MANUAL ACK in Spring Stream - RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I use spring-cloud-stream as a wrapper for RabbitMQ.

In my project I need to use MANUAL ACK. So I have added appropriate configuration/code and it **works** when I turn on the application. Messages are passed and ACK is send back from consumer.

```
  @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT)
  public void foo(@Payload String message,
                  @Header(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL) Channel channel,
                  @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) Long deliveryTag) throws IOException {
    service.bar(message);
    channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
  }
```

Question is:

**I am able to write the test for AUTO ACK but how to write it for MANUAL ACK? I just don't know how to pass** `@Header(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL) Channel channel` **in my test?**

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I have figure out how to do it with mockito:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class FooTest {

  @Autowired
  private Sink sink;

  @MockBean
  private BarService barService;

  @Test
  public void hello() throws Exception {
    //given
    Channel channel = mock(Channel.class);
    HashMap<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
    attributes.put(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL, channel);
    attributes.put(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG, 1);

    //when
    sink.input().send(MessageBuilder.createMessage("test-message", new MessageHeaders(attributes)));

    //then
    verify(barService).bar("test-message");
    verify(channel).basicAck(1, false);
  }

}
```

But maybe someone knows if there is possible approach without mocking the `Channel` in headers?

Answer (score 0):

For a unit test of your listener method, you can just call it directly with the mock

```
foo("test-message", channel, 1L);
```

Sending a message tests the infrastructure too, which you might want to do, for example, if you rely on the framework's message conversion (i.e. send JSON and have a POJO `@Payload` parameter.

Comment: The unit test is not my case. I would like to have integration test which will check also if configuration of my queues is correct. So I need to send the message via the channel instead directly call of handling method.

Comment: In that case, it's not clear what you are asking in your supplementary question in your answer "But maybe someone knows if there is possible approach without mocking the Channel in headers?". What you are doing is correct.

Comment: Just was curious if can do it without mocking the channel so how to allow RabbitMq send the real channel.